# ¿Por qué no se puede obtener el valor de sizeof usado en una clase?

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy "optimizando" el código de algún interprete que estoy haciendo y para ello necesito saber el tamaño en bytes de mi clase `Token`, la cual está compuesta por dos variables: `Type (enum)`, `Value (object)` y un override del metodo `ToString()`:

```
enum TokenType { String, Keyword, Ident, Number, Symbol }

class Token
{
    TokenType Type;
    object Value;
    public override string ToString() { return "Type: " + Type.ToString() + "\t\tValue: " + Value.ToString(); }
}
```

Cuando utilizo una clase para la definicion, no me permite hacer `sizeof` en dicha clase, sin embargo, cuando defino `Token` como un `struct`:

```
struct Token
{
    TokenType Type;
    object Value;
    public override string ToString() { return "Type: " + Type.ToString() + "\t\tValue: " + Value.ToString(); }
}
```

La función `sizeof` por defecto no me permite saber el tamaño, por lo que me las arreglé con el `struct` para que me diera el resultado:

```
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Token))); // Resultado: 16
```

He leído algunas respuestas de SO pero sigo con la misma duda sobre esta función, ¿Por qué no se puede usar `sizeof` de `System.Runtime.InteropServices` ni la función original en una clase, pero si en un `struct`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo no tengo mucha experiencia con c# pero quizas esto sea a lo que usted busca, si al preguntar *por que no puedo obtener el valor* usted quiere alguna alternativa :

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

enum TokenType { String, Keyword, Ident, Number, Symbol }

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // your code goes here
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Token0)));
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Token1)));
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Token2)));
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class Token2
{
    TokenType Type;
    object Value;
    int Value1;
    public override string ToString() { return "Type: " + Type.ToString() + "\t\tValue: " + Value.ToString(); }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class Token1
{
    TokenType Type;
    object Value;
    public override string ToString() { return "Type: " + Type.ToString() + "\t\tValue: " + Value.ToString(); }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct Token0
{
    TokenType Type;
    object Value;
    public override string ToString() { return "Type: " + Type.ToString() + "\t\tValue: " + Value.ToString(); }
}
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/ZqqY9g)

---

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/5s4920fa(v=vs.100).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Técnicamente, lo hice funcionar de alguna manera y me he ahorrado líneas, pero realmente quiero saber el por qué, pienso, "Si `sizeof(int)` retorna 4, ¿Por qué `sizeof(MyCustomObject)` no es igual a la suma de todos sus miembros (excepcionando `string`)?"

Comment: @NaCl no entiendo muy bien lo que dices, pero si usted coge por ejemplo la clase Token0 y añade dentro por ejemplo Token2 Test; ahora le imprime 12, no se si es eso a lo que se refiere. Saludos

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, me refiero a que si en mi código hago `sizeof(Token0)` sin el atributo, no deberia imprimir la suma de los tipos de cada campo?

Comment: @NaCl creo que igual te confundio al poner [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] sobre el struct, si lo borrar puedes ver que funciona igual que si no lo tuviera en este caso, solo es necesario para class hasta donde yo se. Saludos

Comment: Si, ya vi, era que estaba usando `Token1` sin el `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`, gracias!

Comment: @NaCl no se si lo estara teniendo en cuenta o si es le es necesario en su caso o no, pero se lo comento puede que usted calcule unos resultados y estos no sean los que se muestran algunas veces es por la alineacion-padding, no se si sabras sobre esto le dejo un link -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn956973.aspx , (pero no se hasta que punto esto es igual a c++) puede buscar sobre alignment c# o c++ igual encuentra algun mejor recurso que lo ayude si no sabe muy bien como funciona esto. Saludos. P.D: aunque igual ya conoce sobre este tema.

Comment: Me cae como anillo al dedo, mirare eso a ver que me encuentro, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Dice la documentación de [Marshal.SizeOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (el resaltado es propio):

> Devuelve el tamaño, expresado en bytes, de **un tipo no administrado**.

Pero ¿Qué es un *tipo no administrado*? Dice la especificación de C# 3.5, en la sección 18.2 - Pointer types (traducción propia):

> Un tipo no administrado es cualquier tipo que no es un *tipo de
>   referencia* y no contiene campos de *tipo de referencia* en ningún
>   nivel de anidamiento. En otras palabras:
>
> - sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, or bool.
> - Cualquier enum-type.
> - Cualquier pointer-type.
> - Cualquier *tipo de estructura* definida por el usuario que contiene unicamente campos de *tipos no administrados*.

Con lo anterior, se podría concluir que:

- `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))`, Siendo `T` una estructura que contiene un campo String *debería fallar*
- `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))`, Siendo `T` un enumerador *debería funcionar*

Al ejecutar el código vemos que ocurre todo lo contrario, ¿Por qué? El compilador de C# decora de manera predeterminada las estructuras con el atributo StructLayout y el valor *[Sequential layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)* [como dice la documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). ¿Y qué pasa con los Enums? pues *parece* que los trata [con *LayoutKind.Auto*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879787/marshal-sizeof-throws-argumentexception-on-enums#comment26114771_17881440)

Con esta información, y viendo lo que (creo) quieres hacer, me atrevería a decir que esa no es la solución a tu problema y podrías hacer uso, mejor, de algún profiler.